# Argon2i Error - Magento 2 Login

Tags: magento2, login, windows

When logging into Magento 2 for the first time following install, I am getting this error:

Exception #0 (SodiumException): This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: If you are using LAMPP stack  then this answer can help. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331991/this-is-not-implemented-as-it-is-not-possible-to-implement-argon2i-with-accepta#answer-332273

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after upgrading Magento to a version that required a PHP upgrade to 7.4. It would occur when trying to log in with valid admin credentials or creating an admin user via the CLI (admin:user:create).

The fix for me was to install the **sodium** PHP extension. You can check if you already have it with:

> $ php -m

Answer (score 0):

While installing Magento 2.4.2 this error occurs which indicate your PHP and Apache does not have "Sodium" extension ON.

check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/332352/55221 to fix it

Answer (score 0):

you have to upgrad your PHP version to newest one and go to
php.ini file search for sodium extension and activate it by remove the ; before the extension then save the file it will fix it