# This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP

Tags: magento2, error

I am using xampp and it's php version is 7.3.27. I am trying to install magento version-2.4.2 in ubuntu linux. But i am facing this problem.
I have found several solution to install libosodium extension on internet to solve this problem. But it is not clear, how to install it in xampp php folder, not in the usr/bin/php folder. Because i am using xampp php as default php.
[image]

Answer (score 16):

This error occurs with Magento 2.4.2 when php *does not* include the `sodium` php extension.

You can check if this extension is installed with

```
php -i | grep sodium
sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.16
```

To fix this problem install / activate the `sodium` php extension.

For Xampp in `php.ini` add (or uncomment)

```
extension=sodium;
```

Or

```
sudo apt install php-libsodium
```

**NOTE the supported PHP version for Magento 2.4 is PHP 7.4**

Comment: I am using xampp .  In which folder i should install libosodium? And how to install it? I am a beginner in ubuntu, can you help me?

Comment: Check your php.ini file - I have updated my answer.

Comment: I've faced with this issue on Fedora 34.

Command "dnf -y install php74-php-libsodium" to install sodium extension helped.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is only for Linux(Ubuntu) users**

++ Updated

There is default PHP installed as a system package but if you are using self contained installation of PHP (XAMPP [Binami]) then you have to provide **php-config** path in following attribute of `./configure` command while installing the LIBSODIUM for your PHP.

> --with-php-config

I have installed xampp-linux-x64-7.4.15-0 and surprisingly there is no sodium PHP module in this setup. I installed [Sodium library](https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/) first and then install [PHP Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) extesnion for XAMPP.

```
/opt/lampp/etc/php -m    //Check if you have sodium installed 

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autoconf
```

Download stable version of Sodium Library by following link

https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/
libsodium-1.x.x-stable.tar.gz

```
//Go inside the package folder

cd <downloaded package dir>

./configure 

make

sudo make install
```

It will install library and you can check inside the `/usr/local/lib/`. The file for libsodium has been created with *so* extension.

Now we will download and install PHP library for

https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php

//Go inside the package folder

```
cd <downloaded package dir>

phpize   // This will create configure script.

./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config   //This time we provided preferred php config

make

sudo make install
```

This will isntall extension for XAMPP PHP and you can check `sodium.so` file has been created inside `/opt/lampp7.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-2019****`.

**Add extension inside php.ini**

sudo bash -c 'echo "extension="sodium.so"" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini'

Restart XAMPP and check installed php modules

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart

/opt/lampp/etc/php -m
```

If all works fine then you will find sodium in list defiantly.

**CHEERS**

Comment: Hi Kapil 
I'm trying to configure this setup in my xampp server 
First step completed.
but not able to get ./configure command in this php library package folder(as you suggested)
https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php
Can you suggest How I can fix

Comment: Please share what errors are you getting when you execute ./configure cmd

Comment: First I have cloned the codes from https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php
Then I'm going to this(libsodium-php) directory
And executing this ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
command
then I'm getting this error
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
----------------
Because there is no any file from configure name
----------------
Can you suggest how will I execute these commands.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27677/cannot-find-install-sh-install-sh-or-shtool-in-ac-aux
this will help

Comment: I also have updated the answer you can check now.

Answer (score 0):

While installing Magento 2.4.2 this error occurs which indicates your PHP and Apache do not have "Sodium" extension ON.

For WAMP or WAMP64 users, you will need to remove ";" infront of extension=sodium line written in
wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini and

wamp64\bin\php\phpX.X.x\php.ini

then it would be worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are **4 solutions** to resolve this error on **WINDOWS XAMPP**.

**Solution 1:-**

One of the reason for this error is sodium extension not enabled in php.ini file, so we need to enable it and re-run install command in the command prompt.

**To enable:-**

Go to C:\xampp\php\php.ini, find "extension=sodium" in it and then remove semicolon from beginning of this line to enable PHP extensions sodium. Save the file.

Then restart Apache means stop and start Apache from the Xampp Control Panel.

That’s it.