# Magento2: stuck install on 694/1390 Installing user configuration

Tags: magento2

stuck install on 694/1390 Installing user configuration
[image]

I checked log:

```
2021-03-14 11:38:53] main.ERROR: Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled.  [] []
[2021-03-14 11:50:24] main.ERROR: This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP
#0 /home/fsgroup/domains/domain.pl/public_html/vendor/paragonie/sodium_compat/lib/php72compat.php(752): ParagonIE_Sodium_Compat::crypto_pwhash(32, 'password', '8Xp3Q1vUOrJrPoV...', 4, 33554432, 2)
#1 /home/fsgroup/domains/domain.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(594): sodium_crypto_pwhash(32, 'password', '8Xp3Q1vUOrJrPoV...', 4, 33554432, 2)
#2 /home/fsgroup/domains/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(225): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getArgonHash('password', 32, 4, 33554432, '8Xp3Q1vUOrJrPoV...')
#3 /home/fsgroup/domains/domain.pl/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php(71): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getHash('password', '8Xp3Q1vUOrJrPoV...')
#4 /home/fsgroup/domains/domain.pl/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php(97): Magento\Setup\Model\AdminAccount->generatePassword()
#5 /home/fsgroup/domains/domain.pl/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php(83): Magento\Setup\Model\AdminAccount->saveAdminUser()
#6 /home/fsgroup/domains/domain.pl/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1287): Magento\Setup\Model\AdminAccount->save()
#7 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installAdminUser(Array)
```

Comment: If your are using LAMPP stack then this can help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331991/this-is-not-implemented-as-it-is-not-possible-to-implement-argon2i-with-accepta#answer-332273

Answer (score 1):

The error

*`This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP`*

occurs with Magento 2.4.2 when php *does not* include the `sodium` php extension.

You can check if this extension is installed with

```
php -i | grep sodium
sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.16
```

To fix this problem install / activate the `sodium` php extension.

**NOTE the supported PHP version for Magento 2.4 is PHP 7.4**