# magento 2.4.2 p2 setup in wampp server local

Tags: magento2

magento 2.4.2 p2 setup in wamp server local

I have tried to install magento2.4.2 on my local machine below error show
`This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP` also add screenshot
I have already add in php_libsodium.dll file also add php.ini fie still issue show me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAqn8.png

Comment: Any solution please send here

Comment: extension=php_libsodium.dll extension=sodium this both line add in php.ini file also wampp server restart

Answer (score 0):

Please check if libsodium is installed and activated for PHP, it might not be and then you would have to restart WAMP:

```
php -i | grep sodium
sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.16
```

You might also want to check is thread for more tips to solve your issue [This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331991/this-is-not-implemented-as-it-is-not-possible-to-implement-argon2i-with-accepta)

Comment: yes libsodium alerdy add in php.ini file also add ext directory